# Create Order REST API endpoint returning 'Entity Not Availble' for OrderItem in Sandbox

Tags: rest-api, rest, order

I'm using the REST API Create Order endpoint (`/services/data/v49.0/commerce/sale/order`), but when I try and POST to it in my sandbox I get the following:

```
"[ {
"errorCode" : "ALL_OR_NONE_OPERATION_ROLLED_BACK",
"message" : "[There was an error inserting the entity OrderItem. Reason: Entity not available]"
} ]"
```

I've enabled Orders in the console, the permissions are as permissive as they need (the user can create the OrderItem manually), but nothing seems to change the response. Also, it seems to happen no matter how many fields I send or don't send.

Any advice much appreciated!

After some back and forth with Salesforce support, I was advised to rebuild my sandbox. This seemed to make it work again.

Comment: Have you checked (the debug logs) if any of the following is causing this error: validation rule, missing required field, apex trigger?

Comment: Yep, there's nothing in the debug logs saying any type of error has occured

Comment: Hope you might have ensured that the debug logs is enabled to finest level before checking. As such, there is nothing much to infer from your question about the root cause. Suggest you to add more details to the question.

Comment: I had done that, and there's nothing there showing any errors or similar - this is with FINEST on Workflow and Apex. I'm not sure what more details to add?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/te-chris/88160fc6e091420677be5201d6e7dfff here is the log output I'm getting

Comment: I've now turned off all process builder/flow and workflows and it still returns the same error. Logs: https://gist.github.com/te-chris/dcf6afc88bfabae566da026d9d47b666

Comment: If you can provide the source code in the question, it may help in further troubleshooting.